# Can not connet to mysql server 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, server

I'm trying to connect to mysql workbench but I get the following error

Error Message Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306: Could not open database.

Please: 1. Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1

```
Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)

Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines).

Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting.
```

i installed mysql server too in with workbench.help me

Comment: things to try before asking SO: 1) Google. 2) try accessing MYSQL through command line. 3) Try seeing what services are being run on what ports.

Comment: Is MySQL running on port 3306? Does the `root` user have rights to connect? Are you providing the correct password?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows operating system

Comment: Sorry already solved