# Error Message: Cannot Connect to Database Server

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to set up my SQL environment:

- MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
- MySQL Community Server 8.0.16 - macOS 10.14 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive (I have't found lower version)
- MySQL Workbench 8.0.16 mysql-workbench-community-6.3.10-macos-x86_64.dmg

I am following this guide: https://youtu.be/7S_tz1z_5bA?t=836
For me when I click on "Test Connection" it gives the following error message:

```
Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found

Please:
1 Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
2 Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
3 Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines) 
4 Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you're connecting from
```

I have found UNANSWERED questions similar to mine for PC and Linux.

- [Can not connet to mysql server 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451111/can-not-connet-to-mysql-server-127-0-0-1)
- [Cannot Connect to Database Server mysql workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950399/cannot-connect-to-database-server-mysql-workbench)

Someone recommended [Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded) that it solves my question. It is not even the same error message because it asks about and error

```
Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: 
dlopen(/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found
```

Comment: Have you done what the system is telling you to do ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' cannot be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded)

Comment: @nacho I am new to programing. I just know how to follow that video. I used the same password when it has asked for it. I have created that advanced password as well as in the video https://youtu.be/7S_tz1z_5bA?t=386

Comment: @Matt I have read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194719/authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-cannot-be-loaded but it have nothing to do with my post, not even the same error message.

Comment: @filt: Are you sure? It seems like the exact same error, word for word. Could you expand on why it isn't the same e.g. Additional information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use PostgreSQL it is much more simple than MySQL

Their main website: https://www.postgresql.org/

From here you can download the version you want for macOS: https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/

I recommend the postures app because it has a GUI: https://postgresapp.com/

For client I recommend pgAdmin 4: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/

There is a tutorial video as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCMXbM5J0X8

Answer (score 1):

you can change the encryption of the password like this.

```
ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'youpassword';
```

Comment: Is this a terminal command? Because I cant get in to start programing SQL at all at this point.

Comment: @filt run this in ur terminal :`netstat -apv TCP` tell me what u see